# Show Win+; emoji dialog programmatically using API call with Win+X hotkeys disabled

Tags: windows, winapi, uwp, windows-10, autohotkey

I have disabled Win+X hotkeys in Windows (using registry) and use them with AHK. But I want to try new emoji feature in Windows 1803. It's annoying to go click the keyboard taskbar and navigate to it. I just want to show the main popup dialog using AHK.

[image]

Something like:

```
#;::ShowEmojiDialog
```

How do I call it?

Comment: The emoji picker dialog is not (currently) exposed as a Windows Runtime type. And once it is (if ever), you're going to have to make that available to a Desktop application. Using [UWP controls in desktop applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/xaml-host-controls) still has many limitations.

Comment: @IInspectable Is it possible to send virtual `#;` event to explorer.exe, and make it respond to it (when Win+X is disable through registry (I am open to enable it again for a moment if it's possible))